# dynamic linking:change of the linking path

Tags: c++, c, unix, dll

Normally it happens that when ever the path of the library that has to be linked dynamically is defined in LD_LIBRARY_PATH or it it will be mentioned  with -L flag while creating the binary.

In actual scenario  if ,lets say the binary has been built and deployed at the client place.
Now if there is a change in the path of one of the dynamic link library path.
then we need to supply a new make file to all the clients where the binary was deployed.

is there any other method where we need not tell all the clients to change their makefiles and can something can be done in the code itself?
if yes...could anybody please suggest how?

This was ironically an interview question that was asked to me and i didnot have the answer for it.

**EDIT:**: *I was specifically asked about what can be done in the code without touching the makefile.*

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH has nothing to do with linking. It's for runtime only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the interviewers wanted to know about dlopen and dlsym?
http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlsym

Comment: Yes...probably this is what they were expecting.thanks a lot for the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you should only change the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, unless this might be related to a compilation with a hard-coded search path: [rpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath_(linking)).

Answer (score 0):

Use environment variable, like `MYLIBPATH`, and use this variable in your makefile, rather than hard-coded value.

So every client can have own directory structure, and as long as they correctly specify `MYLIBPATH`, your program builds ok.

Alternatively you can look for library in your makefile, like this

```
LIBPATH = $(shell find / -name libmylib.a -exec dirname {} ";" -quit)

myprog: myprog.c
        $(CC) myprog.c -lmylib -L$(LIBPATH)
```

**EDIT:** `locate` replaced with `find` that returns just first match with `-quit` option

Comment: Yeah..this was actually my answer...but this was not agreed by the panel.they wanted sth that can be done in the code

Comment: See updated answer - it uses POSIX `find` so it must be ok on all Unixes

Comment: Using an environment variable is the correct answer.  That the panel thought it should be done another way is not relevant here.  We can't read their minds.